# YouTube API -- extracting title and videoId attributes to build hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api

The following is a JavaScript file that searches through YouTube video data using its API. Down at the bottom you'll see the onSearchResponse() function, which calls showResponse(), which in turn displays the search results.

As this code from Codecademy stands, a [HUGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wlHU.png) amount of information gets printed relating to my search term.

Instead of all that, can I simply display a hyperlink using the **title** and **videoId** attributes? How would I go about altering responseString in showResponse() to build that link? Thank you!

```
// Your use of the YouTube API must comply with the Terms of Service:
// https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms

// Helper function to display JavaScript value on HTML page.
function showResponse(response) {
    var responseString = JSON.stringify(response, '', 2);
    document.getElementById('response').innerHTML += responseString;
}

// Called automatically when JavaScript client library is loaded.
function onClientLoad() {
    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', onYouTubeApiLoad);
}

// Called automatically when YouTube API interface is loaded (see line 9).
function onYouTubeApiLoad() {
    // This API key is intended for use only in this lesson.
    // See link to get a key for your own applications.
    gapi.client.setApiKey('AIzaSyCR5In4DZaTP6IEZQ0r1JceuvluJRzQNLE');

    search();
}

function search() {
    // Use the JavaScript client library to create a search.list() API call.
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
        part: 'snippet',
        q: 'clapton'
    });

    // Send the request to the API server,
    // and invoke onSearchRepsonse() with the response.
    request.execute(onSearchResponse);
}

// Called automatically with the response of the YouTube API request.
function onSearchResponse(response) {
    showResponse(response);
    console.log(response);
}
```

Here is the corresponding HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/styles.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My YouTube API Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <div id="response"></div>
    </section>
    <script src="javascripts/search-2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onClientLoad" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Your advice is much appreciated!

Comment: What is a hyperlink using `title` and `videoId` you are trying to make exactly? Can you give an example?

Comment: Thanks for your response! Does [this](http://i.imgur.com/F5Srism.png?1) help? I want to use the title as the HTML text and the videoId as part of the URL that the text links to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be what you are exactly trying to do.

```
function showResponse(response) {
  var html = response.items.map(itemToHtml); 
  document.getElementById('response').innerHTML += html;
}

function itemToHtml(item) {
  var title = item.snippet.title;
  var vid = item.id.videoId;
  return generateHyperlink(title, vid);
}

function generateHyperlink(title, vid) {
  return '<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + vid + '">' + title + '</a><br/>';
}
```

This code show up links named `title` having YouTube video link using `videoId`.

Comment: This works! I see you've basically drilled down into the properties in the JSON response. This generates links for five results and displays them perfectly. How would I augment this to display only one result?

Comment: I improved my answer to make anonymous function being able to reuse. Just use `itemToHtml` function with specific item (e.g. `itemToHtml(response.items[0])`).

Comment: When I replace **item** with **response.items[0]**, I get the following error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'. Expected a ')' or a ',' after a parameter declaration. Is there a problem with using dot notation in a function definition?

Comment: Don't change parameter to that. Change `var html = response.items.map(itemToHtml)` statement to `var html = itemToHtml(response.items[0])`.